# iphone - trying to understand @property

Tags: iphone

Suppose I have two classes. In the first one I declare this in Class1.h

```
@interface Class1 : UIViewController {

  NSString *myString;
  id myObject;

}
```

On the second class I go beyond that I declare it like

```
@interface Class2 : UIViewController {

  NSString *myString;
  id myObject;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id myObject;
```

and then I **@synthesize myString, myObject** on Class2.m

Then, on my main program, I create two objects: one based on Class1 and another one based on Class2.

What effect the @property of class2 will have? Will every value assigned to both values on Class2 be always retained? If so, do I need to "release" them? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read [Declared Properties section of The Objective-C programming language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1)
for a full explanation on properties ;)

In Class2:

In this case you set `retain` attribute to your property it is supposed to be retained in the implementation. This is done automatically when you synthesize a property.
This means that you should have

```
- (void) dealloc{
    [myString release];
    [myObject release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

and everything should be fine

In Class1, you don't have properties so myString and myObject is not visible from outside. But this does not mean that you shouldn't release them. It depends on the way you initialize them and/or if you send retain messages to them.

BTW, if you set `assign` a property you don't release it, just set it to nil in the dealloc method. If you set `copy` to it then you must release it.

**EDIT**

You said: *But suppose I have this *

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *myView;
```

*and*

```
myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame]; 
[self.view addSubview:myView]; 
[myView release];
```

*? I am already releasing myView... do I have to release it again???*

First, since you have your property defined that way, you should have dealloc method as:

```
- (void) dealloc{
    [myView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

So, the answer is NO you should not release it but actually is not correct.
Please take a look:

```
myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];  //myView retainCount is 1
[self.view addSubview:myView];  //retainCount is 2
[myView release]; //retainCount is 1 again
```

later in dealloc method

```
- (void) dealloc{
    [myView release]; // retainCount becomes 0, is deallocated
    [super dealloc]; // subviews of self.view are released but myView was already deallocated!, so you have over released myView once ;(
}
```

This is the correct way: (Use your properties ;) )

```
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame]; // init, retainCount is 1
self.myView = aView; // retainCount becomes 2
[aView release]; // retainCount becomes 1 again and we are fine.

[self.view addSubview:self.myView]; //retainCounts becomes 2 again.
```

even if it is 2 there is no problem because when self.view is deallocated its subviews also will be released. Hence self.myView retainCount will become 1 again later when self is deallocated.

```
- (void) dealloc{
    [myView release]; //retainCounts becomes 1
    [super dealloc];  // all its subviews of self.view are released hence myView retaincount becomes 1 and is released corretly
}
```

What is the difference?

Suppose self.myView is also retained by other object X and with the former approach, X's view will be pointing to an invalid object, because it was already released.

Hope it helps

**EDIT2**
As bbum's indication, this is a mini-mini-short tutorial on properties:

when you have

```
@property (... retain) NSObject *retainVar;
@property (... assign) NSObject *assignVar;
@property (... copy) NSObject *copyVar;
```

and you @synthesize them

is like having the following setters:

```
// retain
-(void)setRetainVar:(NSObject *)var {
     if (retainVar != var) {
        [retainVar release];
        retainVar = [var retain];
    }
}
//assign
-(void)setAssignVar:(NSObject *)var {
     assignVar = var;
}
//copy
-(void)setCopyVar:(NSObject *)var {
    if (copyVar != var) {
        [copyVar release];
        copyVar = [var copy];
    }
}
```

*(this means that if you assign  directly an object you have to make sure is something equivalent to above setters, from the memory management point of view)*

and your dealloc method should be something like:

```
- (void) dealloc{
    [retainVar release];
    assignVar = nil;
    [copyVar release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

When setting your ivars

for example, inside of init:

```
- (id) init{
    if ((self = [super init])){

        //this is ok
        retainVar = [[NSObject alloc] init];//but is retainVar was not nil we will have a leak ;(

        //This is better
        NSObject *obj = [NSObject alloc] init];
        self.retainVar = obj;
        [obj release]; 

        //this is BAD
        assignVar = [[NSObject alloc] init];//because this is like retaining it, later it will leak

        //below is correct
        NSObject *obj = [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
        assignVar = obj;

        //copy is pretty much like retain,
        //this is ok
        copyVar = [[NSObject alloc] init]; //but, if copyVar was not nil is a leak!

        //below is better
        NSObject *obj = [NSObject alloc] init]:
        self.retainVar = obj;
        [obj release];

     }
     return self;
}
```

Comment: You need to discuss the difference between. Directly setting the instance variables and doing so through the setter/getter in regards to retain/release.  As it is, this is misleading.

Comment: @bbum - can you create an answer explaining what you mean?

Comment: @nacho4d - release, right? But suppose I have this @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *myView; on .h and then on .m I have myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];  [self.view addSubview:myView]; [myView release]; ? I am already releasing myView... do I have to release it again???

Comment: Nice update;   one last nit.   **Never** call or use `retainCount`.  The absolute retain count of an object is neither useful nor something you should be concerned about.

Comment: You are right...`retainCount` should not be used. Is just I couldn't find a better way to explain the change in the count ;)

Comment: "Retain count +1", "retain count -1" is better;  i.e. it is always deltas.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!! Apple should hire guys like you to write their docs, because their docs stinks. This is the way to explain something, covering all aspects and not as they vaguely do. Thanks!!! ∞+1!!!

Comment: just one small question: why do you refer to the retainVar sometimes as self.retainVar but when you dealloc you say just [retainVar release];... is it indifferent? Can I use either ways? thanks.

Comment: Since there is no customized getter like `- (NSObject *) retainVar{...};` the default, or synthesized one will be used. That is, return retainVar. That is why in this case [self.retainVar release] and [retainVar release] are the same.

Comment: (... continues... ) is no alloc of that mutable array in the implementation. Or this is black magic or I am not getting properties totally yet... and there are other strange things, as declaring a UIActionSheet as readwrite, assign... why in the hell would someone declare something readwrite if the code is not meant to be used by another person?

Comment: array implementation? Regarding readwrite and readonly, if you are writing a library and you don't want to expose everything then readonly you will use. But internally you can redefine the same property as readwrite (using categories or extensions). Regarding assign, retain and copy it depends on you and the way you wan't to manage memory as well. (For example have you noticed that delegates are 99% of the time assign? That is for avoiding retain loops, A retains B, B retains A, both never get released)

Answer (score 1):

Apple's "Learning Objective C - A Primer" tells you about that and more:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/